# Error de jaxws-maven-plugin en java 1.8

Tags: java, webservice, java-ee, maven

estoy intentando realizar un cliente para un Web service muy sencillo, una suma de 2 valores, pero al intentar usar **jaxws-maven-plugin** **con java 1.8** me salta un error en el POM y no soy capaz de resolverlo, espero que me podáis ayudar.

```
Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool failed - check output (org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.4.1:wsimport:default:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool failed - check output
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.exec(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:488)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.WsImportMojo.processWsdlViaUrls(WsImportMojo.java:369)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.WsImportMojo.executeJaxws(WsImportMojo.java:288)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.MainWsImportMojo.executeJaxws(MainWsImportMojo.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.execute(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:389)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
```

Soy muy nuevo en el uso de Maven y sus plugins así que es posible que sea una tontería, muchas gracias de antemano.

El POM.XML

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.clona.pol</groupId>
 <artifactId>clientesumaws</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
   <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
   <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/</url>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>wsimport</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <wsdlUrls>
        <wsdlUrl>http://localhost:8080/ServicioSumarImplService/ServicioSumarImpl?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
       </wsdlUrls>
       <packageName>clientews.servicio</packageName>
       <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar tu `pom.xml` e indicar si tienes  agregadas variables de ambiente para Java y Maven y que tu IDE este usando el JDK para compilar y no el JRE.

Comment: Y ver si antes de este texto salen otros mensajes dando más detalles; este lo único que dice es "ha habido un error, mira los mensajes de más arriba para ver los detalles".

Comment: Pues no soy capaz de encontrar mas mensajes es el único  error que muestra eclipse en el Marker.

En lo que respecta al JDK en el JAVA_HOME tengo el 1.8, y en el proyecto de Eclipse también

Muchas gracias por echarle un vistazo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado!
He especificado la versión del plugin a la 1.12 en lugar de la 2.4.1, y ya me ha funcionado.
Gracias por ayudarme en lo posible.

Comment: Disculpa `Arfeon`, me gustaría saber cómo llegaste a la conclusión de que había que cambiar la versión del plugin. Estoy enfrentando un problema parecido, y aunque escribo la versión 1.12 sigue lanzando el mismo error.

Comment: Simplemente estuve investigando en varios sitios y comentaban que podía haber un error en la versión 2.4.1 con el uso de java 1.8, así que baje de versión a la 1.12 que vi que era la recomendada para lo que quería realizar, hace bastante tiempo ya así que no te puedo dar mucha más info. Intentaré recuperar el proyecto que realice si dispongo de él y reviso si tengo algún apunté en el código.
Te da el mismo error que me salió a mi supongo?
Intenta abrir un hilo o colgar el stack de errores que te da para ver si te podemos echar una mano, a veces el error se parace per pude dar mas info.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema. Resultó que tenía "C: / Usuarios / Juan Jiménez" y por el acento estaba arrojando el error. Cuando borré "Jiménez" me funcionó correctamente. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Es importante revises la información que te proporciona Mauricio, realiza el  [tour] del sitio!, te sugiero eliminar esta publicación.